# Use a DS3231 RTC module and Arduino to fire function every other day

Tags: arduino

I'm attempting to create a timer which reminds me to do something ever other day, however it seems that my options with the DS3231 module allows me to set an hour or a day of the week. Unfortunately neither option is good enough (if only there were 8 days in a week) and i'm at a loss on how to tell it to fire every other day.

I considered the idea of setting a 'not_today' variable which will probably work but that has the downside of relying on the arduino and not the RTC which means if it loses power then that variable will reset.

It looks like the DS3231's alarm functionality doesn't really have this option and any code-based solution will have the aforementioned power-loss problems.

Is there an RTC module which can do what I need it to do?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use eeprom to store some state to dance around the limitation?  Seems that would sidestep the power loss issue.

Comment: I'm sure there isn't a reason. I just didn't know enough about this stuff to know I could do that. Thanks though, that's probably the perfect solution :)

Answer (score 1):

User @RamblinRose pointed me in the direction of EEPROM writing and reading which I wasn't aware was possible. This solved my issue. Here is the full code for anyone else coming here and wanting a more comprehensive answer:

```
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

// Init the DS3231 using the hardware interface
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

Time t;

bool active = false;
void setup()
{
  // Setup Serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // The following lines can be uncommented to set the date and time
  // rtc.setDOW(MONDAY);     // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  // rtc.setTime(15, 51, 0);     // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
  rtc.setDate(14, 9, 2017);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
}


int blinker(int state = 1) {
  if(state == 1) {
    if (active == true) {
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(500);              // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(12, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(500);  
      buttonCheck();
    }
  }
}

int buttonCheck() {
  if(digitalRead(11) == 0) {
    active = false;
    blinker(0);
  }
}


void loop()
{
  t = rtc.getTime();
  int hour = t.hour;
  int min = t.min;
  int sec = t.sec;

//  //  Send time to serial monitor (for debugging)
//    Serial.print(hour);
//    Serial.print(":");
//    Serial.print(min);
//    Serial.println(" ");

  // Put there different timers in here for demo purposes
  // Set activation time
  if(hour == 13 && min == 31 && sec == 00) {
    if(EEPROM.read(0) == 0) {
      active = true;  
      EEPROM.write(0, 1);
      Serial.println("Not run recently, activating");
    } else {
      active = false;  
      EEPROM.write(0, 0);
      Serial.println("Run recently, skipping this one");
    }
  }

  if(hour == 13 && min == 35 && sec == 00) {
    if(EEPROM.read(0) == 0) {
      active = true;  
      EEPROM.write(0, 1);
      Serial.println("Not run recently, activating");
    } else {
      active = false;
      EEPROM.write(0, 0);
      Serial.println("Run recently, skipping this one");
    }
  }

  if(hour == 13 && min == 45  && sec == 00) {
    if(EEPROM.read(0) == 0) {
      active = true;  
      EEPROM.write(0, 1);
      Serial.println("Not run recently, activating");
    } else {
      active = false;
      EEPROM.write(0, 0);
      Serial.println("Run recently, skipping this one");
    }
  }

  blinker();
  delay(1000);  
}
```